# Wrong results after using FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE flag for 2D complex FFTW

Tags: 2d, fftw

I'm using FFTW to compute a 2D complex to complex FFT using this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "defines.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>


int main(void)
{
    fftw_complex *in,*out;
    fftw_plan plan;
    int rows=64;
    int cols=64;
    int i;
    in  = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*rows*cols);
    out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*rows*cols);

    for (i=0; i<rows*cols; i++)
    {
       in[i][0] = input_data[2*i];
       in[i][1] = input_data[2*i+1];;
    }
    printf("### Setting  plan  ###\n");
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(rows, cols, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    printf("### Executing plan ###\n");
    fftw_execute(plan);
    for ( i = 0; i <rows*cols; i++ )
    {
       printf ( "RE = %f \t IM  = %f\n",in[i][0], in[i][1] );
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I changed the FFTW flag from `ESTIMATE` to `EXHAUSTIVE` in order to allow the planner to choose the optimal algorithm for this 2D FFT but I got an all-zeros result. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the flag `FFTW_ESTIMATE`, the function `fftw_plan_dft_2d()` tries to guess which FFT algorithm is the fastest without running any of them. Using the flag `FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE`, that function runs every possible algorithm and select the fastest one. 
The problem is that the input is overwritten in the process.

The solution is to populate the input array **after** the plan creation!

See [documentation of planner flags](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html):

> Important: the planner overwrites the input array during planning unless a saved plan (see Wisdom) is available for that problem, so you should initialize your input data after creating the plan. The only exceptions to this are the FFTW_ESTIMATE and FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY flags, as mentioned below.